# How to restore Redis db?

Tags: redis

I am following the [documents](https://www.w3resource.com/redis/redis-backup.php) about how to restore Redis and I am at complete loss at this point.

The document says

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SAVE 
OK
```

*This command will create the dump.rdb file in your redis directory.*

Which it does, it creates the exact same file for me in `/usr/lib/redis` which is alright I guess.

*To restore redis data just move redis backup file (dump.rdb) into your redis directory and start the server. To get your redis directory use CONFIG command can be used. The CONFIG GET command is used to read the configuration parameters of a running Redis server.*

```
127.0.0.1:6379> CONFIG get dir
1) "dir"
2) "/var/lib/redis/6379"
```

Here is where it makes no sense to me. The `.rdb` file for me is already saved in `/var/lib/redis/` and I have no sub folder to that. I don't understand what `"dir"` is doing there and how I can restore my database.

Please enlighten me. I don't seem to be able to save it or I cannot find it perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so basically, the `rdb` file saved in `/var/lib/redis/` is saved every time the server stops and this can be moved to another folder and be used as a point for restoring every time `redis` service starts.

Comment: Are you using RDB persistance?